# Swift: How to check in AppDelegate if user is already logged in

Tags: ios, swift, deployd

My login with Deployd and Alamofire is working completely fine. Here is the code:

```
    let credential = NSURLCredential(user: "username", password: "password", persistence: .ForSession)
    let parameters = ["username" : "username", "password" : "password"]
    Alamofire.request(.POST, "http://xxxxxxxxxxxx/users/login", parameters: parameters)
        .authenticate(usingCredential: credential)
        .response { request, response, _, error in
            if response!.statusCode == 200 {
                self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loggedIn", sender: self)
            } else {
                print("invalid credential bro!")
        }
    }
```

How can I check in the `AppDelegate` if the user is already logged in? I am using the Deployd API on a custom server for user authentication and would like to hide the 'Login Screen' (`LoginViewController`) if the user is already logged in and has an active session.

Comment: check `NSUserDefaults` to save little amount of data

Comment: @NeilGaliaskarov I have already tried doing that but what would be the best practice?

Comment: maybe, you should check if current access token != nil ?

Comment: @bat Sounds Cool! lemme try, thanks.

Comment: @SatnamSingh should i post this in answer?

Comment: @bat Can you please tell me how to check 'current access token', I didn't find the solution.

Comment: @SatnamSingh you can hold it in UserDefaults if you logged succesfully
and then check like this:   `if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(ACCESS_TOKEN) as! String).isEmpty {//do some stuff}`

Comment: @bat thanks! go ahead, post it as answer.

Comment: @SatnamSingh maybe you should check in API currentAccessToken without holding it in UserDefaults?Like in the Facebook API?

Comment: @bat Yes, I'm still looking for a go.

Answer (score 2):

Just check if `access_token` exists, like in FB API. Or you can hold it in `NSUserDefaults` if you logged successfully:

```
if currentAccessToken != nil {
    print("User logged in")
}
```